# IS It possible one vehicle can visit a node in the route of another vehicle

Tags: vehicle-routing

The idea IS to visit a node simultaneously by two vehicles
Or separately  by a time Windows.  I need to program a VRP solución with these constraints. One: the node IS visited by several vehicles.
2. one node must be visited after the another one.